# In my Dockered Django application, my Celery task does not update the SQLite database (in other container). What should I do?

Tags: django, sqlite, docker, celery

This is my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "3"  
services:  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx_airport
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./docker_nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./timezone:/etc/timezone
    depends_on:
      - web
  rabbit:
      image: rabbitmq:latest
      environment:
          - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=admin
          - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=asdasdasd
      ports:
          - "5672:5672"
          - "15672:15672"
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /app/start_web.sh
    container_name: django_airport
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./timezone:/etc/timezone
    expose:
      - "8080"
    depends_on:
        - celerybeat
  celerybeat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /app/start_celerybeat.sh
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./timezone:/etc/timezone
    depends_on:
      - celeryd
  celeryd:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /app/start_celeryd.sh
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ./timezone:/etc/timezone
    depends_on:
      - rabbit
```

Normally, I have a task that executed every minutes and it updates the database located in "web". Everything works fine in development environment. However, the "celerybeat" and "celeryd" don't update my database when ran via `docker-compose`? What went wrong?